# use a script tag for a javascript template instead of a string

Tags: javascript, html, templates, underscore.js

So I've seen handlebars templates do this:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">  </script>
```

and am wondering if there's a way to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) templates like this. It would be really nice to have my templates in markup instead of sitting inside a string.

Comment: Why not just use handlebars? (Caveat: I love handlebars.)

Comment: You can use that script tag trick for anything you want.

Comment: @Pointy care to elaborate?

Comment: That trick is just a way of getting content into the DOM without being parsed as HTML (or anything else).  You can get the contents of the script via `.innerHTML` and use it for anything, including any template library of your choosing.

Comment: @Pointy care to answer with an example or a resource I could at?

Comment: Steve H's answer sums it up; it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this easily.

```
var templateText= document.getElementById('some-template').innerHTML;
```